# How is .Random.seed initially created?

Tags: r, random

I'm aware that it's possible to set the seed by using `set.seed`, but restarting an R session gives a new seed every time. According the [R Documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Random.html):

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current time and the process ID when one is required. Hence different sessions will give different simulation results, by default.

I looked through the [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Global-environment) guide, but it only describes what `.Random.seed` is, rather than how it is initially created.

How does R create the seed at the beginning of a session?

EDIT: Thanks to @sascha's suggestions, I found where the current time and PID are combined. There's a [function called TimeToSeed](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4d6982a64955659a9bdc64e4873c09d99ffc4e3c/src/main/times.c#L149) which combines the PID and time into a single integer. It looks quite simple, but I'm not well-versed enough in C to understand it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to know this?

Comment: You will find the code in ```src/main/RNG.c```, but it's ugly. Function ```RNG_Init(RNGtype kind, Int32 seed)``` is used with time as input for seed.

Comment: @sascha I was looking into what it would take to save the rng state, reseed it for one operation that needs to be unique, then restore the rng state. I looked into how R seeds the RNG, but I couldn't find anything. I'll look into the source, thanks.

Comment: The rng-state is of course dependent on the rng. It will of course be different if MT is used vs. some LCG. Does an object-based copy of the RNG not work (i don't know what R supports; the internal-state of the RNG is the only thing which needs to be saved and has nothing to do with seeds -> a state is usually much bigger than a seed)? And i still don't get your use-case. What do you mean by unique? Why not use *another rng* for this outsourced sample / use two different *random-streams*?

Comment: The .Random.seed object contains the RNG used. It's the first element. Basically, I would like to generate a random number without affecting the current state of the RNG. The random id is for sending to a web service that requires it (yeah, I know), but I'd rather that this not affect the rng state of the actual statistical process.